# Importing database takes a lot of time

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to import a table that contains 81462 rows in a dataframe using the following code:

```
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=server.database.windows.net; DATABASE=server_dev; uid=user; pwd=pw') 
query = "select * from product inner join brand on Product.BrandId = Brand.BrandId"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
```

And the whole process takes a very long time. I think that I am already 30-minutes in and it's still processing. I'd assume that this is not quite normal - so how else should I import it so the processing time is quicker?

Comment: try to import small part of data and check if connection is OK

Comment: Already did. Works fine with 200, it imports almost instantly.

Comment: how's it go with `FETCH NEXT 10000` ?

Comment: add `chunksize`

Comment: @VikasP even if I add `for chunk in pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn, chunksize=500):
    df=chunk` it still takes a lot of time.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am not quite sure where that Fetch Next belongs, though. I will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RomanPerekhrest. FETCH NEXT imported everything within 1-2 minutes.

```
SELECT product.Name, brand.Name as BrandName, description, size FROM Product inner join brand on product.brandid=brand.brandid ORDER BY Name OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 80000 ROWS ONLY
```